# How to get the offset of the window's scroll position in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two elements.

The first is `#div1` and the second is `#div2`.

Each of them has a height of near 350 to 500 pixel. I want to know if the current scroll position of the window is greater than `#div1` and lower than `#div2`.

I have done this:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > $("#div1").offset().top
 && $(window).scrollTop() < $("#div2").offset().top)
{
 doSomething();
}
```

Though the above does not work because the way offset and scrollTop are measured seems to be different. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: It should be `$(window).scrollTop()`, shouldn't it?

Comment: It is not a good idea to fix pointed problem in question's text (by editing it), but nevertheless: can you provide [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with persisted problem?

Answer (score 0):

Putting it in the function `scroll()` on window will help as it will check for the `scrollTop` value and the `div`s offset while scrolling.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() > $("#div1").offset().top
   && $(window).scrollTop() < $("#div2").offset().top)
  {
    doSomething();
  }
});
```

EDIT: `$(window).scrollTop` will not return anything, it should be `$(window).scrollTop()` as said in the comment.

Comment: Why don't you mention in your answer that you changed `scrollTop` to `scrollTop()`? It's actually the main point of question.

Comment: @Regent, Oh yes. It's true. Thank you for the notice.

Comment: See the updated question. It doesn't work. Because the window calculates its scroll differently than the offset of the elements. So that my elements returns their offset as 3000 while the window returns its scroll as 1000.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi, How can the window calculate differently? Try this. Log the `$(window).scrollTop()` on scroll and from the top of your page, scroll 5 times(i.e your middle button make 5 click sound) then tell me the value of `$(window).scrollTop()`

Comment: Normally it should be around 570.